# ¿Como subir un proyecto Symfony a un Hosting?

Tags: php, html, symfony, hosting, framework

---

> **Contexto:** Tengo problemas al momento de subir mi proyecto en Symfony 5 a DreamHost (Hosting pagado).

---

***TENGO EL SIGUIENTE ERROR:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

> **MI GUIA:**

- Trate de seguir los pasos de [ESTA GUIA](https://medium.com/@runawaycoin/deploying-symfony-4-application-to-shared-hosting-with-just-ftp-access-e65d2c5e0e3d)

---

> **ESTADO:**

- Subí mi proyecto en 2 partes:

***---------------------------> [Symfony]***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***---------------------------> [Public]***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Mi index tiene la siguiente configuración.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]:

---

> **Conclusión:** Soy nuevo en symfony y no tengo muy claro el como arreglar esto.

---

Comment: Buenas, en este enlace (https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html) existe el tutorial de como subir a producción tu proyecto.

Comment: También lo intente, pero llegado el momento de subir al Host, me pierdo y básicamente se repite el mismo error.